# PHP Scrape Mp3 File

Tags: php

I am embedding some mp3 files on my website. The problem is some of the names are different and my website does not know how to embed - unless I define all the files with the correct names.

For example,

`http://example.com/chapter1/book-[some random name].001.mp3`

I have set up my website so it embeds like this

`http://example.com/chapter1/book.001.mp3`

Is there any possible solution that I can use with php so it auto fills the `[some random name]`.

Comment: Most webservers tend to work on the basis that the links you put into them point at the actual files. Do you want to auto-generate those links? look into `DirectoryIterator` or even `glob`. if you're doing it manually, then bite the bullet and put in the proper filenames yourself, or rename your files to match the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options,

1. Output the path to the file correctly (easiest)
2. Build and store a registry of the mp3s in a db or flat file and use mod_rewrite to pass the parameters to a loader script. (Example below)

> ```
> <?php 
> /* mod_rewrite  .htaccess in chapters folder
> RewriteEngine On
> Options -Indexes
> RewriteBase /chapter1
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^(.*).mp3$ index.php?loadmp3=$1 [L]
> */
> $mp3_dir='./mp3s/';
> //Example passed url: http://localhost/chapter1/book.002.mp3
> if(isset($_GET['loadmp3'])){
>     $real_path = get_mp3_list($_GET['loadmp3']);
>     if($real_path != false){
>         //Result:  ./mp3s/book-next_random_name.002.mp3
>         print_r($real_path);
>         //Pass the url to a streamer script
>     }else{
>         //not found
>     }
> }
> ```

```
/**
 * Build & cache, search for mp3 from array
 */
function get_mp3_list($search){
    global $mp3_dir;
    if(file_exists($mp3_dir.'mp3s.json')){
        $list = json_decode(file_get_contents($mp3_dir.'mp3s.json'),true);
    }else{
        $mp3s = glob($mp3_dir."*.mp3");
        $list = array();
        foreach($mp3s as $mp3){
            if(preg_match("#(\w+)-(\w+).(\d+).mp3#", $mp3, $match)){
                $list[]=array('location'=>$mp3,
                'type'=>$match[1],
                'name'=>$match[2],
                'episode'=>$match[3]);
            }
            if(!empty($list)){file_put_contents($mp3_dir.'mp3s.json', json_encode($list));}
        }
    }

    $search = explode('.',$search,2);
    foreach($list as $mp3){
        if($mp3['type'] == $search[0] && $mp3['episode'] == $search[1]){
            return $mp3['location'];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
/*
$list Example Array 
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [location] => ./mp3s/book-next_random_name.002.mp3
            [type] => book
            [name] => next_random_name
            [episode] => 002
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [location] => ./mp3s/book-some_random_name.001.mp3
            [type] => book
            [name] => some_random_name
            [episode] => 001
        )

)
*/
?>
```

Hope it helps